# rewrite directory on url with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

On my website I have a /profile.php.

I also have a directory named /profile/.

I am wondering if I could use .htaccess to rewrite

"/profile/[username]"

to be

"/profile?name=[username]"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean change /profile/abc to /profile.php?name=abc?

Comment: actually, I already have a setting in my .htaccess that allows you to take off the .php ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a file `/profile.php` I believe you want to redirect it to `/profile.php?name=[username]` instead of `/profile?name=[username]`

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

In case you still want to redirect to `/profile?name=[username]` you can change above rule to `/profile?name=$1`

Comment: actually, I already have a setting in my .htaccess that allows you to take off the .php ending.

Comment: ok no problem you still should be able to use this code.read the answer carefuly.

Comment: Yes, I believe this worked for me (I am getting some other errors, but I think they do not apply to .htaccess) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /profile?name=$1 [QSA,NC]
```